# Can't extract data from RESTClient response

Tags: groovy

I am writing my first Groovy script, where I am calling a REST API.

I have the following call:

```
def client = new RESTClient( 'http://myServer:9000/api/resources/?format=json' )
```

That returns:

```
[[msr:[[data:{"level":"OK"}]], creationDate:2017-02-14T16:44:11+0000, date:2017-02-14T16:46:39+0000, id:136]]
```

I am trying to get the field `level`, like this:

```
def level_value = client.get( path : 'msr/data/level' )
```

However, when I print the value of the variable obtained:

```
println level_value.getData()
```

I get the whole JSON object instead of the field:

```
[[msr:[[data:{"level":"OK"}]], creationDate:2017-02-14T16:44:11+0000, date:2017-02-14T16:46:39+0000, id:136]]
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `path` is the URL path you're hitting, not the path of the elements in the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't looked at the docs for RESTClient but like Tim notes you seem to have a bit of a confusion around the rest client instance vs the respons object vs the json data. Something along the lines of:

```
def client = new RESTClient('http://myServer:9000/api/resources/?format=json')
def response = client.get(path: 'msr/data/level')
def level = response.data[0].msr[0].data.level
```

might get you your value. The main point here is that `client` is an instance of RESTClient, `response` is a response object representing the http response from the server, and `response.data` contains the parsed json payload in the response.

You would need to experiment with the expression on the last line to pull out the 'level' value.